# Should Logstash shipper or indexer perform filters?

Tags: logstash

I am running two instances of Logstash, one as a "shipper", one as an "indexer".

I want the shipper to pick up logs and forward them to the indexer using lumberjack.
The indexer writes to elasticsearch.

In order to do filtering, **where should the filters be defined**? On the shipper? Indexer? Both?

Example filters are key+value extraction and timestamp identification.

It is also unclear from the documentation how lumberjack encodes/decodes the messages, so I'm not sure what I'm dealing with.

(for bonus points, will the answer also work with logstash-forwarder?)

Using Logstash 1.4.2. Configuration below.

Machine "shipper"

```
input{
  file{
    path=>["/var/log/blah.log"]
    tags => ["java", "some info"]
    codec=>multiline{
      pattern=>"^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
      negate=>true
      what=>previous
    }
  }
}

filter{ 
  # ???
}

output{
  lumberjack {
    hosts => ["10.1.1.1"]
    port => 5000
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
  }

}
```

Another machine: "indexer" (10.1.1.1)

```
input {
 lumberjack {
    port => 5000
    type => "logs"
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
}

filter{ 
  # ???
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that when outputting over lumberjack, the shipper's field-extraction filters may be ignored. The output codec is the deciding factor. See http://serverfault.com/questions/612877/using-logstash-as-shipper for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logstash is designed to fit your infrastructure wherever possible, so you can organize your shippers and indexers however you want. You can run them all on the same server, on separate nodes, or even in multiple layers.

I can imagine circumstances where I might do some filtering on shippers. Perhaps multiline collection to keep incoming events simple, or other short-term analysis that doesn't involve a lot of heavyweight `grok` work.

Usually, though, you'll want to keep shippers lightweight, since those servers are presumably focused on running important applications other than Logstash. If that's your goal, it will make sense to run most or all of your filters on indexer node(s).

Answer (score 0):

Acutally I think both shipper and MQ(Redis or Kafka) are used to improve the throughput of ELK.You can do all the works(collect,filter,and forward)in a node if there are just a few log data,however,if there are many log file needed to be watched,then it's better to separate these works in different node, shippers collect log data,MQ act as a buffer and can do some load balance work,and indexer act as a filter do the heavyweight filter work.In this circumstances,it is better to make the shippers as simple as possible.